# CakePHP baking self-joined models

Tags: cakephp, model, self-join

I am trying to setup a self join and having hell.

For example, a User has a ContactList, which is just other Users. So ContactList is a join table connecting User to itself.

User

id | name

ContactList

id | user_id | friend_id

After baking however, im not getting the result i expect. I've googled solutions but they dont work for me. How is this kind of situation handled? Do i need to customize the model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to set up your associations manually, per the [CakePHP book [Associations]](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html).

How can CakePHP know what you're referring to with "friend_id" if there's no "friends" table?  Hint: it can't.

There are plenty of great examples in the book on the page about Associations (the link above).  Read through it and you'll most definitely have a better understanding.

It's not really considering "customizing the model" by doing things that aren't baked for you.  Baking is just a quick way to get the bare-bones up and rolling, but it can't be expected to do ALL the work.

Answer (score 0):

`bake` is able to generate a self referencing relation (only) if you specified a field named `parent_id` in your database